# Using a custom value as a local variable

Tags: c++, console-application, local-variables

What I want to do is to use a custom value as a local variable (in code this looks something like this):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
fstream someFileStream;
someFileStream.open("RandomFileName.txt");
 double a0;
 double a1;
 double a2;
 double a3;
 string SomethingString;
 int counter = 0;
 for (int counter = 0; counter <= 3; counter++) {
 getline(someFileStream, SomethingString, '\n');
 double SomethingDouble = stod(SomethingString);
 'a'+counter= SomethingDouble; //This line of code gets an error
/*
I want to make it so that the 'a'+counter is used as a local variable name and the SomethingDouble gets stored in the following doubles: a0, a1, a2, a3;
*/
 }
someFileStream.close();
return 0;
}
```

If this is not possible, then I might try another solution rather than using a custom value for the local variable name. Also please **don't use arrays** in the answer (I'm writing a program for an assignment, in which arrays are not allowed)

I tried looking all across the internet, but it seems as if nothing has been done like this before, so I couldn't find how to make it work.

Comment: There is nothing at all like this in C++.  Since it's an assignment, you'll need to look at it carefully to see what non-array thing they want you to use--is it just `std::vector`?

Comment: What about creating your own class instead of using a builtin vector or array?

Comment: "It seems as if nothing has been done like this before" Well, plenty of things have been done like this. But they haven't had an arbitrary "no arrays allowed" restriction, so they've used an array, because everything you've described about what you're trying to do makes it seem like arrays or containers are an extremely natural fit. I would suggest talking with your instructor or TA about what they have in mind, if using arrays is forbidden.

Comment: What is the entire problem? Your solution - a custom value as a variable - might not be the best fit for it.

Comment: You want an array/vector.  that lets you do `array_name[index]` to access index'th element.

Comment: The closest suggestion I can give you is to create a table using `unordered_map<string, string>` to map string names to values. Let me know if that's of interest.

Comment: @kenntnisse, in reply to you comment, the original problem is to take input from 5 different files containing the monthly rainfall levels for 12 months there is new line after every value. The program has to output average monthly rainfall per year (per file), and has to output the month and the value of the rain that it rained the most (the values in the files are in chronological order). The output is supposed to look like this [link](https://pastebin.com/wMPcRZzL) . I asked this question just to save myself some time and instead of writing a switch for all the values, I tried this question.

Comment: If anyone wants to look, here is the incomplete source code (feel free to provide any feedback). [link](https://pastebin.com/ruztdCe3)

Comment: Um, if that is your problem in total, why are trying to use 5 (sets of) variables. This is an XY problem. you just need 1, calculate each file & output, move on to the next with the same (set of) variables.  - Edit - Oh, your trying to do months - you don't need to keep all that info around - you need running total and max month only, no?

Comment: @AviBerger, in reply to your comment, yes, I only need to calculate the max month, and it's value. But I don't see how it will be possible with just the variable for a month, as I need to be comparing all 12 variables for 12 months to see which variable is the largest - that is not possible with less than 12 variables for months, right?

Comment: Not unless you need them for some other purpose. In essence: runningTotal += curMonthRainfall; if ( provisionalMaxRainfall < curMonthRainfall ) { provisionalMaxRainfall = curMonthRainfall; provisionalMaxMonthName = curMonthName } in the middle with the necessary additional stuff before and after. Compare & revise as you go rather than read all then do all comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since using a counter value in the name for an assignment seems to be impossible in `c++`, the next closest thing to solving this problem was hard-coding a switch into the while loop:

```
 for (int counter = 0; counter <= 3; counter++) 
{
   getline(someFileStream, SomethingString, '\n');
   double SomethingDouble = stod(SomethingString);
   switch(counter){
     case 0: a0 = SomethingDouble; break;
     case 1: a1 = SomethingDouble; break;
     case 2: a2 = SomethingDouble; break;
     case 3: a3 = SomethingDouble; break;
     default: cout<<"This isn't supposed to happen\n"; break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what a map or hash table is? That's really what you want, but you didn't specify if you assignment would let you use it or not.  Also, this feels like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @selbie I have written down what I'm trying to achieve with this in the comment on the question. Please see that comment if interested.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the XY problem, @selbie, now I figured out an alternate (and easier) approach to this problem.